Pac4j handling multiple IDP signing keys for SAML2.0
I noticed that the Identity Provider metadata url from a customer's o365 saml integration had multiple signing keys as compared to my other customers.
This customer with multiple signing keys is unable to sign in,
We get the error
org.pac4j.saml.exceptions.SAMLSignatureValidationException
Signature is not trusted

Do I need to configure pac4j to handle this case? Are multiple signing keys even supported?
How do I go about this?
The trustengine does not trust the signing on the assertion in the saml response.
org/pac4j/pac4j-saml/5.7.2/pac4j-saml-5.7.2-sources.jar!/org/pac4j/saml/profile/impl/AbstractSAML2ResponseValidator.java:142


You need to export the metadata of O365 (a XML file) and configure pac4j to use it: https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/saml.html

I have already done that. What specifically do you mean? I provide the metadata url to pac4j. I do this for all other customers. Except that this customer seems to have multiple signing certificates.

I haven't done this test, but you see the multiple signing certificates in the IdP metadata right? If so, this is not supported by pac4j yet. Feel free to submit a contribution for that.

Yes I can see the multiple certs n the IDP metadata. Thanks for the information. Will do that
